# SQLException Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, sql, unit-testing, junit, controller

I am attempting to write a JUnit test for a query which is retrieved via a textbox in an html form. The text retrieval has been tested and works but my unit test is failing. I am using 2 relevant classes: QueryController and QueryControllerTest. I have been playing around with when and what I am closing in these two classes and keep getting the error: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed.

**QueryControllerTest.java**

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class QueryControllerTest {

@Test
public void testQuery() {
    ResultSet testRs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String connectionUser = "root";
        String connectionPassword = "GCImage";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,
                connectionUser, connectionPassword);
        Query testQuery = new Query();
        testQuery
                .setQuery("select * from service_request where FN_contact = 'Greg'");
        testRs = QueryController.executeSelect(conn, testQuery);

        assertEquals("Laughlin", testRs.getString("LN_contact"));
        assertEquals("Hello World", testRs.getString("Notes"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            testRs.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

**QueryController.java**

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class QueryController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/query")
public String processRegistration(@ModelAttribute("query") Query query,
        Map<String, Object> model) {

    String queryString = query.getQuery();

    if (queryString != null && !queryString.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("query (from controller): " + queryString);
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
            String connectionUser = "root";
            String connectionPassword = "GCImage";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,
                    connectionUser, connectionPassword);
            if (queryString.toLowerCase().startsWith("select")) {
                ResultSet rs = executeSelect(conn, query);
            } else {
                int rowsUpdated = executeUpdate(conn, query);
                System.out.println(rowsUpdated + " rows updated");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

    return "query";
}

public static ResultSet executeSelect(Connection conn, Query query) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query.getQuery());
        while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString("ID");
            String firstName = rs.getString("FN_Contact");
            String lastName = rs.getString("LN_Contact");
            String notes = rs.getString("Notes");
            System.out.println("ID: " + id + ", First Name: " + firstName
                    + ", Last Name: " + lastName + ", Notes: " + notes);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(rs!=null){
                rs.close();
            }
            if(stmt != null){
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return rs;
}
}
```

Comment: A `ResultSet` is part of the `Statement` and `Connection` from which it was created, when they are closed, so is the `ResultSet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QueryController.executeSelect is calling rs.close(), but then your assertEquals in QueryControllerTest.testQuery are calling methods on testRS. As executeSelect is returning the resultset, closing it first doesn't make sense. Further, executeSelect is being passed the connection, so it shouldn't be closing that either (what happens if the caller wants to do two different selects on the same connection?).

Comment: ive tried deleting the rs.close() statement in executeSelect() but get the same exception

Comment: Closing a connection closes associated statements which then close associated resultsets, so you probably can't close anything if you want the resultset back, which means you'll have to refactor into open, execute, close methods.

Comment: Oh, whoops. I missed you're passing the connection in, so executeSelect shouldn't really be closing anything, just let the close of the connection close everything.

Comment: That's because in executeSelect, you're looping over all the rows in the resultSet (the while (rs.next()). By the time you get back to testQuery, you've retrieved all the rows in the resultSet, so testRS.getString(...) has no row to get the column from. You *may* be able to call testRS.first() to go back to the first row, but not all DBs and DB drivers support that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you are creating two connections. Try to only instantiate the connection of `QueryController` class for your test. You will need to provide the connection. After you store it in a variable to run the query.

`Connection con = QueryController.getConnection ()`;

Comment: processRegistration isn't being called by testQuery, so testQuery is only using one connection. I assume than in normal usage processRegistration would be used, but the poster's writing a test for executeSelect so has to set it up in a similar way to processRegistration, which means creating a connection in testQuery. And yes, it could be cleaned up a little bit, for example so the URL, user, and password don't have to be specified twice, but that's left as an exercise for the reader. :-)